# Java Regex expression to match and store any integers

Tags: java, regex

Right now, using Java, I just want it to be able to tokenize any string of integers to an array

input = `1dsa23f hj23nma9123`
array = `1,23,23,9123;`

I have been trying a few different ways to do it, `string.matches("")` and then tokenising after it's in the right format and what not but it is too limiting to the user.

Comment: Try some tutorials.  This should be a simple expression: https://regex101.com/r/wN8oO5/1

Comment: You can't just change your question into different one since that would invalidate already posted answers. If you have new question ask it in new post.

Comment: @ergonaut - I am trying to use what i have already learned from tutorials. I have not seen this one yet so i'll see how I go.

Comment: Each edit is saved so you can see it (just click `edited ... ago`). In this case you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37323762/3.

Comment: In your previous comment (which is now deleted) you claimed you understand what I said about changing your question into new one. So why you are still doing it?

Comment: @pshemo how about this - I understand, but considering the fact that I cannot post another question for 3 days due to my current question not being well received (I'm sorry that the first question I'd ever posted wasn't up to the communities standards) I chose to edit my question and ignore your advice considering its urgency. I was\am really tired and hence short tempered. I guess I will just wait.

Comment: Lets try other way. I will try to help you with your new question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37323762/5)) here via comments, and this question will stay as it is.

Comment: Your regex can look like `number(, number){zero or more times)`. `number` can be represented as `\d+` (one or more digits). So using this approach your regex could look like `"\\d+(, \\d+)*"`. Also remember that `text.matches(regex)` is checking `regex` can match *entire* `text`.

Comment: About your original solution `!responses.matches("[\d]{1,} ([,]{1} [\s]{1} [\d]{1,}){0,}")` `{1}` is always redundant, you should be able to replace in your regex `{1,}` with `+` and `{0,}` with `*`. You also don't need to surround any standard character class like `\d` and `\s` with `[...]` (only reason to do so would be to create union of such classes like `[\d\s]` which would represent character which is `space or digit`. Also possible reason why it didn't work is that spaces are also considered as valid characters, so if you write ` \s ` regex will see it as `space anyWhitespace space`.

Comment: Anyway I upvoted this question as it wasn't terrible (seen worse question which ware not even first questions). Hope it will reduce your 3day limit a little. Also it would be nice if you could respond to answers posted to current question (I know if may not be the real case, but still it was your question so it is your judge about what answers you expected).

Comment: @Pshemo What you've put in is great and really helpful, hopefully I'll get it sorted out. Thanks for also being respectful despite my tantrum. It's for an assignment which is due in three days. There are so many issues still.

Comment: @Pshemo I've just implemented that into my project. `!responses.matches("\\d+ (, \\d+){*}")` but I get illegal repetition errors when using + and *.

Comment: Repetition can be represented as `{min,max}` (where `max` is optional). If you want to represent "zero or more" you would need to write it as `{0,}`, but since this is very common repetition we can represent it as `*` precisely to avoid these four characters `{` `0` `,` `}`. So don't write `{*}` (since it really doesn't make sense for regex). Simply use `*` instead (just like you used `+`).

Comment: Also notice that you are requiring form comma `,` to be surrounded by space from both sides. Most often we don't add space before `,` but after it, so your regex could probably look like `"\\d+(, \\d+)*"` (or maybe remove spaces at all if you are parsing something like CSV file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for something like

```
String[] nums = text.split("\\D+");
```

`\D` regex is negation of `\d` (it is like `[^\d]`) which means `\D+` will match one or more non-digits.

Only problem with this solution is that if your `text` start with non-digits result array will start with one empty string.

If you still want to use `split` then you can simply remove that non-digits part from start of your text.

```
String[] nums = text.replaceFirst("^\\D+","").split("\\D+");
```

---

Other approach than `split` which is focusing on finding delimiters would be focusing on finding parts which are interesting to us. So instead of searching for non-digits lets find digits.

We can do it in few ways like `Patter`/`Matcher#find`, or with `Scanner`. Problem here is that these approaches don't return array but single elements which you would need to store in some resizeable structure like List.

So solution using Pattern and Matcher could look like:

```
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(yourText);
while(m.find()){
    numbers.add(m.group());
}
```

Solution using Scanner is similar, we just need to set proper delimiter (to non-digit) and read everything which is not delimiter (delimiters at start of text will be ignored which will should prevent returning empty strings).

```
List<String> nums = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourText);
sc.useDelimiter("\\D+");
while(sc.hasNext()){
    nums.add(sc.next());
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me ! Thanks for taking the time to improve your answer :) It shouldn't matter, but you could add a `numbers.toArray(new String[0])` to your second solution in case OP needs an array result. Also, using `sc.hasNextInt()` and `sc.nextInt()` in your third solution would make it possible to directly produce a `List<Integer>` rather than a `List<String>`

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I could do it but I don't know if result should be `String[]` or `int[]` so I left it as it is.

Answer (score -1):

```
final String input = "1dsa23f hj23nma9123";
final String[] parts = input.split("[^0-9]+");
for (final String s: parts) {
    final int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Comment: This would fail if the `String` did not start and end with a digit, since an empty part would be produced by the split. See [here](https://ideone.com/D5IxXx)

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!